# Error when running SharePointDSC.Reverse

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, installation, configuration

Version of DSC

> ReverseDSC v. 1.9.2.6
>   SharePointDSC.Reverse

```
Error
Specified PSDSCRunAsCredential (NDC\svjsirdspfarm) is the Farm Account. Make sure the specified PSDSCRunAsCredential isn't the Farm Account and try again

VERBOSE: Leaving BeginProcessing Method of Get-SPManagedAccount.
VERBOSE: Leaving ProcessRecord Method of Get-SPManagedAccount.
VERBOSE: Leaving EndProcessing Method of Get-SPManagedAccount.
Specified PSDSCRunAsCredential (NDC\svjsirdspfarm) is the Farm Account. Make sure the specified PSDSCRunAsCredential isn't the Farm Account and try again
```

Checked the permission of the farm account. Tried using different non farm account, no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you have to make sure:

- Account under which you login should have the Shell Admin (Add-SPShellAdmin) access to load the SharePoint PowerShell access
- the account which you provide in the script should be farm admin.

I am sure the user you are seeing in the error is the user under which you login on the server. Try to login with farm admin account and run the script.

Comment: I have setup a demo farm with only one admin and farm account  -- spadmin. I login with the spadmin account, installed SharePoint and I still get the same error.  Even with only one saccount (SPADMIN)

Comment: Thanks - that worked once i verified the account settings.